# install HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath getting failed

Tags: linux, perl, shell, unix, html-tree

I am trying to install ** HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath of version 0.13 ** but it gets failed.

Can anyone suggest what could be the cause.

Comment: It probably has something to do with whatever error message was produced when it failed.

Comment: @cjm actually when i am running make test than it shows the following info

Comment: PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath....
#   Failed test 'use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;'
#   at t/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath.t line 7.
#     Tried to use 'HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath'.
#     Error:  weaken is only available with the XS version of

Comment: Scalar::Util at /root/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/blib/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm line 98
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/blib/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm line 98.
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 4) line 2.
t/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath....NOK 1Can't locate object method "findvalue" via package "HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath" at t/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath.t line 27.

Comment: # Looks like you planned 29 tests but ran 1.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1 run.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 1.
t/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath....dubious                                          
        Test returned status 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
DIED. FAILED tests 1-29
        Failed 29/29 tests, 0.00% okay
t/pod.......................skipping, Test::Pod required
t/pod.......................ok

Comment: t/pod_coverage..............Test::Pod::Coverage 1.00 required for testing POD coverage at t/pod_coverage.t line 6.
t/pod_coverage..............ok                                               
t/test_following............weaken is only available with the XS version of Scalar::Util at /root/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/blib/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm line 98

Comment: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/blib/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm line 98.
Compilation failed in require at t/test_following.t line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/test_following.t line 6.
t/test_following............dubious

Comment: Test returned status 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
t/test_preceding............weaken is only available with the XS version of Scalar::Util at /root/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/blib/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm line 98
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/blib/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm line 98.
Compilation failed in require at t/test_preceding.t line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/test_preceding.t line 6.
t/test_preceding............dubious

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting all these comments.

Comment: actually i am new to stackoverflow so i don't have 10 reputation requiored to post image

Comment: do you get any idea why the problem occurs ??

Comment: Why would you need to post an image?  Just paste in the text & indent it 4 spaces so it shows as code.

Comment: Naveen, That's completely unreadable. Could you edit that information into your question? (Select the text and press Ctrl-K to indent it so it shows up nicely formatted.)

Answer (score 3):

You have a badly installed version of Scalar::Util. (It's might not be your fault; some distros have done this.) Reinstall Scalar::Util first.

```
$ cpan Scalar::Util
```

Or if it complains Scalar::Util is up to date.

```
$ cpan
cpan> force test Scalar::Util
cpan> force install Scalar::Util  # Only do this if the tests were successful!!
cpan> quit
```